# Application of Zariski's Main Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $f: A \to B$ is a local homomorphism, $B$ is isomorphic to a localization of an $A$-algebra of finite type. Let $L$ be the field of fractions of $B$, and suppose that $B$ contains the normal closure $A'$ of $A$ in $L$.

Grothendieck writes (SGA 1, second proof of Theorem 9.5., page 16) that Zariski's Main Theorem implies that $B$ is isomorphic to a localization of $A'$.

Why is this so? I tried applying some algebraic versions of ZMT, but failed to see the implication.

Comment: You are lacking some context. If $A$ is normal and $B$ is a local ring of some blowup of $A$ (e.g. $A=\mathbb C[X,Y]$, $B=\mathbb C[X, Y/X]_{(X, Y/X)}$), then $A'=A$ and $B$ is not a localization of $A'$.

Comment: @cant_log: I'm probably missing something easy, but how does one show that your $B$ is not (isomorphic to) a localization of $A$?

Comment: @rghthndsd: $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ would an immersion, in particular injective. But this is a blowup morphism.

Comment: @cant_log In your example, $A$ is not local though, although I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh: you are right. Let us localize $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ at the origin. This doesn't really make difference.